# Is the decorator pattern really needed here?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am learning the decorator design pattern from the Head first design patterns book. Their example treats different types of coffees as a Beverage. The beverages are decorated with things like milk, soy, whip cream etc. For example, the DarkRoast coffee with mocha and whip cream :
[image: decorator example]

The class diagram :
[image: class diagram]

I understand that this example is used only because it is simple. But, I have an alternate and simpler way to implement this example without decorator pattern. We can have an Item class with description and cost. Then, the Beverage class can have baseCost, totalCost and list of Items.

Does this alternative design have any major disadvantages over the decorator pattern ? Can you give any specific scenarios where the decorator pattern would be better than my design ?

PS - In case anyone wants to see the decorator code : https://github.com/bethrobson/Head-First-Design-Patterns/tree/master/src/headfirst/designpatterns/decorator/starbuzz

Comment: 90% of what you do with decorators can be done by other means. It's a matter of legibility, usability, and abstraction.

Comment: A List introduces mutability, whereas the Decorator Pattern allows runtime customization while preserving immutability.

Answer (score 2):

This [example](https://jasonroell.com/2015/11/10/the-decorator-pattern/) is mainly on **how** to use decorator pattern

> Patterns can be a complex subject and knowing **when** to use them is sometimes more complicated than understanding **how** to use them

See other [examples](https://github.com/IanDarwin/patterns-demos/blob/master/src/main/java/structure/decorator/Mat.java) as `Mat`, where you **add** functionality to object, for example color:

```
public class Mat extends ImageDecorator {
   String color;

   public Mat(String color, PhotoImage target) {
         super(target);
         this.color = color;
   }

   @Override
   public String getDescription() {
        return target.getDescription() + ", Matted(" + color + ")";
   }
```

This is the main reason to use decorator pattern, to add functionality without multiple inheritance

> The Decorator pattern provides a more flexible way to add responsibilities to objects than can be had with static (multiple) inheritance

Answer (score 0):

Here basically a specific beverage is represented by a linked list of ingredients. The `getDescription()` method builds recursively the string representation of the beverage.

In this simple case it's probably okay, but if there are many ingredients, possibly with varying quantity, another data structure could be better (maybe some kind of hashtable, but there are many other possibilities).

For instance, here quantity is represented by duplicated items (so there is no fraction), see for instance the duplicate `Mocha` in `beverage2` in StarbuzzCoffee.java.

You can decide which solution is better by considering the overhead of managing another data structure, vs simplicity of a linked list, keeping in mind that the linked list can be costy if there are many items in it, especially if you need random access to elements. Example: you need O(n) loops (where n is the list size) to check if a beverage has a given ingredient, much less with the hashtable. But for low n, the solution with a hashtable may be slower because it's a more complicated data structure.

The answer to your question depends on the context, but, generally speaking, there is nothing wrong with another approach.

Answer (score 0):

In the example, it is possible to have the same behavior without a decorator pattern. I agree what everyone else is said already. Of course, the example is made just for learning how to work with decorators and recognize the pattern.

I would like to add one point here how I see that problem. (because you said you were learning the pattern)

When you use decorator pattern, it probably doesn’t do anything more than some other implementation. Anyway, the benefit is to use a pattern that is known and you have  ‘a word’ to describe the implementation. Usually, this is important when working with teams because of then you can describe the implementation details efficiently. (when other developers also know the pattern)

When you use own way to implement the behavior, usually it takes time to discuss how it works.

Second benefit is the problem what the decorator pattern try to solve. [Decorator Pattern - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)

- Responsibilities should be added to (and removed from) an object dynamically at run-time.
- A flexible alternative to subclassing for extending functionality should be provided.

I am mentioning this because the use of the pattern can be very useful when working with legacy code / unknown code. Usually, then you need that kind of tricks to add new behavior without modifying the original implementation.